# Node 16.13 with FIPS (OpenSSL 3.0.0)

Tags: node.js, openssl, fips

Has anyone managed to make this work, following the instructions from Node 16.13 BUILDING.md I managed to compile but when I run:

node --enable-fips -p 'crypto.getFips()'

I get:

OpenSSL error when trying to enable FIPS:

*00801AB2C97F0000:error:1C8000D5:Provider routines:SELF_TEST_post:missing config data:providers/fips/self_test.c:289:
00801AB2C97F0000:error:1C8000E0:Provider routines:ossl_set_error_state:fips module entering error state:providers/fips/self_test.c:387:
00801AB2C97F0000:error:1C8000D8:Provider routines:OSSL_provider_init_int:self test post failure:providers/fips/fipsprov.c:706:
00801AB2C97F0000:error:078C0105:common libcrypto routines:provider_init:init fail:crypto/provider_core.c:903:name=fips
There is a couple of mentions of this issue online, but none is resolved.*

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

By default, node looks for a `nodejs_conf` section in your openssl.cnf; when this is unset - node won't load any provider, which might yield the error you've pasted.

Assuming you're working w/ the default openssl.cnf, I suggest either adding `nodejs_conf = opessl_init` just after `openssl_conf = openssl_init`, or alternatively -

you can compile node with the `--openssl-conf-name` config options and change the conf name it looks for (e.g. `./configure --openssl-conf-name=openssl_conf --openssl-is-fips --shared-openssl`, assuming the default config)